# How do I make a seperate thread inside a class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

I have a class `foo` and i put inside a member function a thread object. And i tried to initialize it like this `std::thread mythread(&foo::myprint, this);` inside another function. My problem is that I get the same `thread::get_id` with a different function `foo::mycount` that i need to count something. Both `myprint` and `mycount` uses `this_thread::sleep_for` but they don't sleep separately (something that i want to happen). I follow you up with some code example

```
class foo
{
  void func()
  {
    std::thread mythread(&foo::myprint, this);
    mythread.join();
  }
  void myprint()
  {
    sleep_for(1s);
    cout << count << endl;
  }
  void mycount()
  {
    sleep_for(1ms);
    count++;
    cout << count << endl;
  }
};
void main()
{
  foo obj;
  while(1)
 {
   obj.func();
   obj.mycount();
 }
}
```

I also tried putting `mycount` in another function with a thread object, and I don't if `std::call_once` affected anything, cause i used it inside the `mycount` function. I expected a different `get_id` for different functions.

Comment: You get same thread ids, because your code flow is not multi-threaded due to early join(): `_--_--_` where you want `--===--`

Comment: Creating a thread and then immediately joining it is equivalent to just calling the function in the current thread. You haven't actually done any multithreading here.

Comment: In this case, you could `detach` from the thread, instead of waiting for its completion. Just make sure your thread exits cleanly.

Comment: Also, its not clear from you code if `count` is atomic variable or not. If not, you need to use mutex to synchronize access to it.

Comment: Also, a very careful search of the shown code finds no instance of any obvious calls to  `std::thread::get_id`, so the question is completely unclear.

Comment: Be cautious with `detach`. It is a tool for experienced programmers and is best used rarely and when no other good option exists. Unfortunately it's most often used by beginners who have no idea how badly they are about to screw up.

Comment: Learn about lambda functions they make the syntax a lot easier. I also prefer to use std::async (instead of std::thread).  Also you probably want to synchronize in the destructor of your class.. All you did know is make a synchronous function f (with thread switch overhead).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with a lambda function to start an asynchronous process.
And using std::future for synchronizing the destructor of your class with the background thread (which is counting numbers in this example).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

// dont do "using namespace std"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class foo
{
public:

    foo() = default;

    ~foo()
    {
        // destructor of m_future will synchronize destruction with execution of the thread (waits for it to finish)
    }

    void func()
    {
        m_future = std::async(std::launch::async, [=] { myprint(); });
    }


    void myprint()
    {
        for (std::size_t n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
            std::cout << n << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

private:
    std::future<void> m_future;
};

int main()
{
    foo obj;

    obj.func(); // start thread

    return 0;
}
```